# Remotely Wipe Drive For IT Dept

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

My IT dept will not let me use my Mac (personal computers in general) due to the inability to wipe my drive if I am let go/leave.

So I'm looking for option to offer them. I see iCloud has that ability, but obviously the computer is using my iCloud and such so this does not seem like an obvious solution.

Is there any standard way or software that can give them this control?

Comment: Have you considered running a separate OS on an external drive for all your work stuff so you can simply return the drive? As long as you don't same anything on your hard drive, returning the drive is almost the same thing (just an alternative solution; frankly I wouldn't give someone else the ability to remotely wipe my hard drive).

Comment: @Arc676, I hadn't considered that. While I agree with you on not letting anyone wipe my drive. I'm trying to find a happy medium as they are making a big deal out of me using my Mac.  I bought it just for work and 6 months later they are having issues due to Airmail causing errors on the exchange which I complied immediately and removed. However the external drive is interesting idea and something to most certainly consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of Third Party Software for this purpose. One of them is **Prey**. Prey offers Remote Wipe data for its Home and Personal plan. You could just head over to their site and take sneak peek https://preyproject.com/. I hope I solved your problem :-)

Comment: This is certainly what I was thinking about. I wonder how much the business version would cost as they would most certainly need to license as such.  I do not believe they would be willing to do this just for me, but if I can provide them a 'must' case then maybe they would be willing to look into it. As there is unlikely to be a completely free solution and this question I will accept this as the answer.

Comment: @KirsKringle Thanks. I will let you know if I get across any freeware for this purpose :-D